# linux c-script to rename file by inode

Tags: c, linux, inode

I'd like to rename a file on linux by use of a c-script.

I know how to use rename() to change the name of a file, which takes to strings, "". I also know how to use the linux shell to access a file per i-node and then change the file's name.

But I don't see a possibility, to do that in c without calling the shell.

Is there any function (or workaround) for this procedure?

Comment: What have you tried to far? Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: opendir, readdir, stat, closedir...